# How to append an image to div and then empty it and then appending back to it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am appending an image(img1) to a div using `appendingTo` and then I want to empty that (img1) in the div and append something else(img2) to that. But when I am trying to append (img1) again nothing appears.

```
<div id="countries">
    <div class="fixed">
        <div class="firstRow display all" id="nz">
            <h2>New Zealand</h2>
            <p>Awesome cities and nature</p>
        </div>
        <div class="firstRow display all" id="aust"></div>
        <div class="firstRow display all" id="vietnam"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="secondRow display all" id="fiji"></div>
        <div class="secondRow display all" id="sing"></div>
        <div class="secondRow display all" id="raro"></div>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="cities">
    <div class="fixed">
        <div id="left">
            <div class="bigLeft" id="zero"></div>
            <div class="smallLeft" id="one" style="margin-left: 0px"></div>
            <div class="smallLeft" id="two"></div>
            <div class="smallLeft" id="three"></div>
            <div class="smallLeft" id="four" style="margin-left: 0px;"></div>
            <div class="smallLeft" id="five"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightBar">
            <div id="city1" class="citiesPlace" style="margin-top:0px;"></div>
            <div id="city2" class="citiesPlace" style="margin-top:0px;"></div>
            <div id="city3" class="citiesPlace" style="margin-top:0px;"></div>
            <div id="city4" class="citiesPlace"></div>
            <div id="city5" class="citiesPlace"></div>
            <div id="city6" class="citiesPlace"></div>
            <div id="city7" class="citiesPlace"></div>
            <div id="city8" class="citiesPlace"></div>
            <div id="city9" class="citiesPlace"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="nzImg0" style="display:none;">
    <img src="Images/aust.jpg" style="width: 219px; height: 150px">
</div>
<div id="nzImg1" style="display:none;">
    <img src="Images/nz.jpg" style="width: 219px; height: 150px">
</div>
<div id="nzImg2" style="display:none;">
    <img src="Images/aust.jpg" style="width: 219px; height: 150px">
</div>
<div id="nzImg3" style="display:none;">
    <img src="Images/aust.jpg" style="width: 219px; height: 150px">
</div>
<div id="nzImg4" style="display:none;">
    <img src="Images/aust.jpg" style="width: 219px; height: 150px">
</div>


<div id="austImg0" style="display:none;">
    <img src="Images/aust.jpg" style="width: 219px; height: 150px">
</div>
<div id="austImg1" style="display:none;">
    <img src="Images/aust.jpg" style="width: 219px; height: 150px">
</div>
<div id="austImg2" style="display:none;">
    <img src="Images/aust.jpg" style="width: 219px; height: 150px">
</div>
```

**jQuery Part**

```
$(".all").click(function () {
    $("#countries").fadeOut(500);
    $("#cities").fadeIn(500);

    var j = 1;
    var f = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        if (a[i] == $(this).attr("id")) {

            $(this).appendTo("#zero");
            $(this).find("h2").css("fontSize", "300%");
            $(this).find("p").css("fontSize", "80%");
            $(this).css("height", "100%");
            $(this).css("width", "100%");

            for (var m = 0; m < c.length; m++) {
                $("#" + c[m]).empty();
            }

            for (var f = 0; f < c.length; f++) {
                $("#" + a[i] + "Img" + f + " " + "img").appendTo("#" + c[f]);
                $("#" + a[i] + "Img" + f + " " + "img").css("display", "block");

            }
        } else if (a[i] != $(this).attr("id")) {

            $("#" + a[i]).appendTo("#" + b[j]);
            $("#" + a[i] + " " + "h2").css("fontSize", "100%");
            $("#" + a[i] + " " + "p").css("fontSize", "80%");
            $("#" + a[i]).css("height", "100%");
            $("#" + a[i]).css("width", "100%");
            j++;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what are the contents of `c[]` and `a[]`? could you also post the html?

Comment: var a = ["nz", "aust", "vietnam", "fiji", "sing", "raro"];                                                       var c = ["city1", "city2", "city3", "city4", "city5", "city6", "city7", "city8", "city9"];

Comment: please edit your question to include your HTML code.

Comment: what is `i`? you need to post more of your code.

Comment: I have edited the question! if you can help me it would be a big help.

Comment: Nitpick: Do not do `$("#" + a[i])` over and over. Store it in a variable or use chaining...

Answer (score 0):

When you append the element into the div, you are moving it. When you move it, the original is no longer there. When you empty the div it goes away. So now you can not reference it.

So you either need to not remove the element and just hide it or instead of empty, move the element back to where it originally was.

Comment: So what is your suggestion other than using hide(), because I used it and did not work. I thinking about getting the old element. But idk how.